# Reload page after logout in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reload

I am trying to reload page after logout in angularjs. I am using ui Routing. Only the state is changing, but cache will not be removed. I tried the below scenarios. While using $window.location.reload, browser warning alert(Do you want to reload) is coming. But i don't need alert.

1. $state.go(login);
2. $window.location.reload(true);
3. $location.path('/login')

Can any one please suggest how to remove cache while changing state in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just use `window.location.reload()`, which works great even though it's not angular.

Comment: Alert is coming while using window.location.reload(). I don't want that alert.   Can you please tell me how to remove that alert.

Comment: Natively there is no alert. You must be using some library or framework, or maybe even browser extension, which will add that alert. Angular will not add such alert by default.